# Webpack how to combine 0.bundle with main bundle (PDFJS)

Tags: webpack, pdf.js

I am using the default PDFJS library with webpack and made something work based on this tutorial: 
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/webpack

I've tried to bundle everything into one module using webpack but even specifying one entry point with the following config...

```
entry: {
  'main': './src/main.ts',
  // 'pdf.worker': 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry',
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
}
[...]
```

webpack creates two js files in my `/dist` directory

- `0.bundle.js`
- `main.bundle.js`

If I remove the line `import { PDFJS } from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js'` (which is my only and important dependency) from my main code the `0.bundle.js` file is not created any more but of course my code *does not work any more*.

**Question**

What is causing webpack to bundle things into two modules even I don't want to, and how can i avoid it ?

Note: keeping it this way is not a solution since it's a problem I have to solve on a platform where i can only have one entry file authorized (don't ask me why).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out webpack automatically creates chunks when the code base is too large. Although you might keep that in mind to optimize your app, it's perfectly doable - or even acceptable - to add the following your `webpack.config.js` file.

`plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({ maxChunks: 1 })
],`

This will force code to be bundles into one big `main.bundle.js` file.

Sincerly yours(self),

Myself.

Answer (score 2):

PDF.js has two parts: for display (pdf.js) and for parsing (pdf.worker.js). Display parts loads pdf.worker.js via Web Worker or via `<script>`. (The latter disables worker, and that can cause parsing run on main thread and cause UI locking/jank).

In Webpack context, pdf.js is included in main bundle, pdf.worker.js is compiled as worker and additional bundle to replace script-tag-loading (see https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/). By removing the latter bundle you can kill pdf.worker.js part (which is responsible for parsing). By adding it to the main bundle, you will increase size of main bundle thus increase page initial loading time (or risk main thread to jank).

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer because I'm a bit stuck. In my course code, I defined `pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc` and I can see Chrome loading this file, but it also load 0.min.js. I'd like to get rid of that one and use the former one as the web worker. Indeed, by being able to specify the path of the file to load, I can add a "rev" to prevent caching. With the 0.min.js, I can't and it causes cache issue...